# Splitting a string containing the UTF-8 character "叱"

Tags: javascript, string, cjk

Running the following code in node 14.3.0

```
const data = 'ABCDE漢字でも大丈夫';
console.log(data);
console.log(data.split(''));
```

returns

```
ABCDE漢字でも大丈夫
[
  'A',  'B',  'C',  'D',
  'E',  '�',  '�',  '漢',
  '字', 'で', 'も', '大',
  '丈', '夫'
]
```

Why is the 叱 character not being split properly? I have tested all [jouyou kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji), and this character is the only one that yields this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript split, came before UTF-8 was widely adopted,.  But to prevent breaking existing applications, it was decided not to alter it's implementation that was based on UTF-16.  Luckily, recent ES Specs implemented the `Array.from` for coping with this.

So for your example you can use `Array.from` or the Array spread syntax..

Also RegEx also has the /u option for unicode.  I've also include that..

eg.

```js
const data = 'ABCDE漢字でも大丈夫';
console.log([...data]);

console.log(data.match(/.{1}/ug));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "**叱**" instead "", it`s the same characters.

```js
const data = 'ABCDE叱漢字でも大丈夫';
console.log(data);
console.log(data.split(''));
```